# Are "print world rights in English" the same as "First World Print Rights"?

Tags: publishing, legal, publisher

I am considering selling work to "Shoreline of Infinity" however they say

> We buy first digital and print world rights in English, but your
>   rights are returned to you after 6 months of original publication
>   (digital or print).

I am not familiar with this specific terminology and am unsure if I would be giving up too much or if I have first sold to regional publications if I am no longer offering what they are looking for.

Is this the same as asking for First World English Print Rights? Or am I able to sell First British, First North American etc and then sell them Generic (second) World Rights?

I understand that as I am being asked for digital rights I am unlikely to make any sales after selling to this publication so I need to know exactly what I am being asked for so I know what sales (if any) I can make first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They purchase the right to be the first to publish your work in English anywhere in the world in those formats. You would not be able to sell *first* rights in English anywhere in the world after that.

ETA: I am not a lawyer.

Comment: I guessed that they were demanding that they get to go first in the English speaking world but would that also stop me later selling, say, First Australian Serial Rights?